# Not authenticated access to chat

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

When I join a chat room without authentication, it starts flashing with multiple page reloads, instead of redirecting to the authentication page.

Comment: [Related question on ruSO.meta](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3592/176217)